# Retrieving multi-select array of values from react-select in router 6 action method

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom, react-select

I already know how to use `react-select` and retrieve the multi-selection with `onChange` updating the state (from previous posts). However, I'm now learning `react-router` 6 action method and trying to incorporate `react-select` with it. The routing via `createBrowserRouter` is working properly and action method is triggering when the `SAVE` button is clicked. This is what I have so far:

```
const PostForm = (props) => {
  const options = [
    { value: 'chocolate', label: 'Chocolate' },
    { value: 'strawberry', label: 'Strawberry' },
    { value: 'vanilla', label: 'Vanilla' },
    { value: 'chdfdfdfd', label: 'chdfdfdfd' }
  ]
      
  return (
    <Card className={styles.content}>
      <Form method={props.method}>
        <p className={styles.heading}>Create New</p>
        <input type="text" name="title" placeholder='Enter Title' />
        <input type='file' name='img' />
                
        <Select
          options={options}
          isMulti
          maxMenuHeight={150}
          menuIsOpen={true}
          isSearchable={true}
          placeholder='Select Main Cast'
          className={styles.select}
          name='lstCast'
          id='lstCast'
        />

        <Button handleClick={handlerCancel}>Cancel</Button>
        <Button type='submit' className={styles.submitBtn}>
          Save
        </Button>
      </Form>
    </Card>
  )
}

export default PostForm;

export async function action({ request, params }) {
    console.log(request.method) // working correctly, outputting 'POST'
    const data = await request.formData()

    console.log(data.get('title')) // working correctly
    console.log(data.get('lstCast')) // outputting only first selected value of the multi-selection     
    ...
}
```

Data entered in the input fields is outputting correctly in the `action method` when the `SAVE` button is clicked. However it's only outputting the first selected value of the `REACT-SELECT` multi-selection. Anyone knows how to output ALL the selected values of the `REACT-SELECT` multi-selection in the action method? `"react-router-dom": "^6.10.0", "react-select": "^5.7.3"`.

**Update**: I made some progress but not fully solved as yet. I created some state and updated this state when the `React-Select` `onChange` changes. This state is then binded to a hidden input field so `formData` would read it in the action method as follows:

```
const PostForm=(props)=>{
    const options = [
        { value: 'chocolate', label: 'Chocolate' },
        { value: 'strawberry', label: 'Strawberry' },
        { value: 'vanilla', label: 'Vanilla' },
        { value: 'chdfdfdfd', label: 'chdfdfdfd' }
      ]

    const [selectedValues, setSelectedValues] = useState({})

    //useEffect(()=>{
    //    console.log(selectedValues) // printing out correctly
    //},[selectedValues])
      
    return(
        <Card className={styles.content} >
            <Form method={props.method} className={styles.form} >
                <h2 className={styles.heading} >Create New Film</h2>
                <input type="text" name="title"  placeholder='Enter Title' />
                <input type='file' name='img' />

                <Select 
                    options={options} 
                    isMulti 
                    maxMenuHeight={150} 
                    menuIsOpen={true} 
                    isSearchable={true}
                    placeholder='Select Main Cast' 
                    className={styles.select} 
                    onChange={setSelectedValues} />

                <input name='lstCast' value={selectedValues} hidden readOnly />

                <Button handleClick={handlerCancel}>Cancel</Button>
                <Button type='submit' className={styles.submitBtn}>
                  Save
                </Button>
            </Form>
        </Card>
    )
}
export default PostForm;


export async function action({request, params}){
    const data = Object.fromEntries(await request.formData())
    console.log(data)
    console.log(data.title) // prints correctly
    console.log(data.lstCast) // prints [object Object] for each item selected 
}
```

Output:

[image: Output]

I selected 3 values from the react-select but it's printing out as `[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]` in the action method while it's printing out correctly in the (commented out) `useEffect` in `PostForm`. How can I get the values of the object which was passed from the hidden input to the action method?

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/misty-surf-w1w31h?file=/src/PostForm.js)

Comment: If you make a codesanbox with [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), that would be easier for others to debug and help.

Comment: @MadanBhandari https://codesandbox.io/s/misty-surf-w1w31h?file=/src/PostForm.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you are passing object as value to `input`, as `input`'s default value is `text`, its reading object as string to `[object] [object]`.

To fix this, first you need to stringify json and pass to input. Later on your action, parse this value back to json.

Update your hidden input from

```
  <input name="lstCast" value={selectedValues} hidden readOnly />
```

to

```
  <input name="lstCast" value={JSON.stringify(selectedValues)} hidden readOnly />
```

And in action parse JSON. Instead of `data.lstCast.toString()` to `JSON.parse(data.lstCast)`

I hope this fixes your problem. Here is the link to [updated codesanbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/amazing-jennings-pbkgee?file=/src/PostForm.js).

Answer (score 0):

The simplest and cleanest solution for this is to use the getAll function instead of get function as shown below.

```
const PostForm = (props) => {
  const options = [
    { value: 'chocolate', label: 'Chocolate' },
    { value: 'strawberry', label: 'Strawberry' },
    { value: 'vanilla', label: 'Vanilla' },
    { value: 'chdfdfdfd', label: 'chdfdfdfd' }
  ]

  return (
    <Card className={styles.content}>
      <Form method={props.method}>
        <p className={styles.heading}>Create New</p>
        <input type="text" name="title" placeholder='Enter Title' />
        <input type='file' name='img' />

        <Select
          options={options}
          isMulti
          maxMenuHeight={150}
          menuIsOpen={true}
          isSearchable={true}
          placeholder='Select Main Cast'
          className={styles.select}
          name='lstCast'
          id='lstCast'
        />

        <Button handleClick={handlerCancel}>Cancel</Button>
        <Button type='submit' className={styles.submitBtn}>
          Save
        </Button>
      </Form>
    </Card>
  )
}

export default PostForm;

export async function action({ request, params }) {
    console.log(request.method) // working correctly, outputting 'POST'
    const data = await request.formData()

    console.log(data.get('title')) // working correctly
    console.log(data.getAll('lstCast')) // now also working correctly
    return {}
}
```